# Given local smooth extensions, construct a global smooth extension

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In Spivak's *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, Vol. 1*, he defines a function from a half-space $H^n$ to be $C^\infty$ if there is an extension to a neighborhood of $H^n$ that is $C^\infty$. On page 54, exercise 10(b) asks

> If $f: H^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is locally $C^\infty$, then $f$ is
>   $C^\infty$, i.e., $f$ can be extended to a $C^\infty$ function on a
>   neighborhood of $H^n$.

Perhaps an argument from connectedness would work? Given a point $x$ on the boundary, the condition on a point $y$ that there exists a smooth extension containing both $x$ and $y$ is certainly an open condition. I can't see why it should be a closed one.

Answer (score 2):

Cover $\partial H^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$-neighborhoods $(U_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ on which there is an extension $f_i$...choose a partition of unity $(\varphi_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ subordinate to $(U_i)$ and let the extension be $\sum f_i \cdot \varphi_i$.